# jQuery get specific element on same level

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following structure:

```html
<tr id="Test-Maschine">
  <td><b>Test-Maschine</b>
  </td>
  <td class="ip">127.0.0.1</td>
  <td id="127.0.0.1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="rebootMachine('machine.ip')">Reboot</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="create/" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FsxictNZ43bTBskPIiopyZ7BfOkUUFtj' />
      <input type="hidden" value="Test-Maschine" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
      <button type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn" class="btn btn-link">Container installieren</button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CDummyContainer</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="startContainer('127.0.0.1','CDummyContainer')">Start</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="stopContainer('127.0.0.1','CDummyContainer')">Stop</button>

    <form action="delete/" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FsxictNZ43bTBskPIiopyZ7BfOkUUFtj' />
      <input type="hidden" value="CDummyContainer" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
      <button type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn" class="btn btn-link" onclick="deleteContainer('127.0.0.1','CDummyContainer')">Delete</button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Container1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="startContainer('127.0.0.1','Container1')">Start</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="stopContainer('127.0.0.1','Container1')">Stop</button>

    <form action="delete/" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FsxictNZ43bTBskPIiopyZ7BfOkUUFtj' />
      <input type="hidden" value="Container1" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
      <button type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn" class="btn btn-link" onclick="deleteContainer('127.0.0.1','Container1')">Delete</button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>


<tr id="FritzBox">
  <td><b>FritzBox</b>
  </td>
  <td class="ip">127.0.0.2</td>
  <td id="127.0.0.2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="rebootMachine('machine.ip')">Reboot</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <form action="create/" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FsxictNZ43bTBskPIiopyZ7BfOkUUFtj' />
      <input type="hidden" value="FritzBox" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
      <button type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn" class="btn btn-link">Container installieren</button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; FDummyContainer</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="startContainer('127.0.0.2','FDummyContainer')">Start</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="stopContainer('127.0.0.2','FDummyContainer')">Stop</button>

    <form action="delete/" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FsxictNZ43bTBskPIiopyZ7BfOkUUFtj' />
      <input type="hidden" value="FDummyContainer" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
      <button type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn" class="btn btn-link" onclick="deleteContainer('127.0.0.2','FDummyContainer')">Delete</button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PythonContainer</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="startContainer('127.0.0.2','PythonContainer')">Start</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="stopContainer('127.0.0.2','PythonContainer')">Stop</button>

    <form action="delete/" method="post" style="display: inline !important;">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='FsxictNZ43bTBskPIiopyZ7BfOkUUFtj' />
      <input type="hidden" value="PythonContainer" name="mytextbox" size="1" />
      <button type="submit" value="Click" name="mybtn" class="btn btn-link" onclick="deleteContainer('127.0.0.2','PythonContainer')">Delete</button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>
```

In short as output:

```html
Table:
- Machine
- Container
- Container
- Machine
- Container
// and so on
```

Machines and Containers are both on the same level: as .
Now I want to get all the Containers of the previous Machine excluding the Machine to manupulate their online status, which is

```html
<td id="127.0.0.1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" disabled="disabled">...</button>
  </td>
```

I tried

```html
$('.btn').filter(function(i, v) {
                            return $(v).parent().parent().prev().children(':first').children(':first').text() == "{{machine.name}}" && $(v).parent().prev().text() == '';
                        }).text("off").removeClass('btn-link').addClass('btn-danger');
```

But obviously that only works for ONE element, not for the following n more elements.

Comment: Since your question is about client-side technologies, don't quote the Python templates that *generate* what the client-side code will see; quote what actually goes to the browser. The question is also completely unrelated to Python.

Comment: So given a machine, you want all the tr´s before the machine that don´t have an id?

Comment: No, I want all Container which are below one particular Machine

Comment: From your example only machines have ids. Would you stop when another machine is found? In your output example, clicking on first machine would match 2 containers or more?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You brought me an idea. I can give the elements a class with the name of the machine.

Comment: What you have is a list of machines, each with a list of containers — yet you put them in a table... I assume to get them to display the way you want. This is Bad™.  Design your markup to reflect the correct _structure_ of your data; you can make anything look any way you want with CSS. `<ul class="machines"><li class="machine"><span class="mname">Test-Maschine</span> <span class="ip">127.0.0.1</span><ul class="containers"><li class="container"><span ...>` etc. Now a machine node is the _ancestor_ of a container node, so just climb the tree to find it (jQuery `.closest()` does that).

Comment: _"I can give the elements a class with the name of the machine."_ Since the machine names are unique, and this will identify each one, an `id` is more appropriate than a `class`.

Comment: Yes you're right, that is not that good. I will rework it like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would probably simplify this if you used `<tbody>` to create groups. You can have as many `<tbody>` as you want in a table

```
<table>
   <tbody>
        <tr class="machine">...
        <tr class="container">...
        <tr class="container">...
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
        <tr class="machine">...
        <tr class="container">...
        <tr class="container">...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Then when iterating machine class it's associated containers would be it's siblings

```
$('tr.machine').each(function(){
   var myContainers = $(this).siblings();
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a good approach. Didn't know that I can have multiple bodies.